# Issue with two identical services

Tags: c#, linq, web-services

Can anyone solve this I have two services identical almost but yet one fails on a get request after an update has been done?

```
        public void UpdateCarType(string carregistration, CarType cartype)
        {
            var findcar = cartypes.Where(s => s.CarRegistration == carregistration).FirstOrDefault();

            if (findcar != null)
            {
                findcar.CarRegistration = cartype.CarRegistration;
                findcar.CarModel = cartype.CarModel;
                findcar.CarMake = cartype.CarMake;
                findcar.CarColour = cartype.CarColour;
                findcar.CarEngineSize = cartype.CarEngineSize;
                findcar.CarHireCostPerDay = cartype.CarHireCostPerDay;

            }
```

This is the operation contract:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "/UpdateCarType/{carregistration}")]
    void UpdateCarType(string carregistration, CarType cartype);
```

This is the client side update and get requests:

Update:

```
    private void button29_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string uriupdatestaff = string.Format("http://localhost:8002/Service/UpdateCarType/{0}", textBox30.Text);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<CarType>");
        sb.AppendLine("<CarRegistration>" + textBox30.Text + "</CarRegistration>");
        sb.AppendLine("<CarColour>" + this.comboBox6.Text + "</CarColour>");
        sb.AppendLine("<CarEngineSize>" + this.comboBox7.Text + "</CarEngineSize>");
        sb.AppendLine("</CarType>");
        string NewStudent = sb.ToString();
        byte[] arr = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(NewStudent);
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriupdatestaff);
        req.Method = "PUT";
        req.ContentType = "application/xml";
        req.ContentLength = arr.Length;
        Stream reqStrm = req.GetRequestStream();
        reqStrm.Write(arr, 0, arr.Length);
        reqStrm.Close();
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        MessageBox.Show(resp.StatusDescription);
        reqStrm.Close();
        resp.Close();
    }
```

Get:

```
    {
        string uriGetdates = "http://localhost:8002/Service/CarType";
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(uriGetdates);
        var dates = xDoc.Descendants("CarType")
            .Select(n => new
            {
                CarRegistration = n.Element("CarRegistration").Value,
                CarModel = n.Element("CarModel").Value,
                CarMake = n.Element("CarMake").Value,
                CarColour = n.Element("CarColour").Value,
                CarEngineSize = n.Element("CarEngineSize").Value,
                CostPerDay = n.Element("CarHireCostPerDay").Value,
            })
            .ToList();
        dataGrid10.ItemsSource = dates;
    }
```

My automatic thought was because im only defining car colour and car engine size that the rest of the fields are null, but the exact same operation but with customers does not do this and it returns the list into the datagrid even if i only update one field.

The error I get is `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` when I try to relist the updated cartype.

Comment: Where abouts is the error thrown?

Comment: You haven't initialised a variable before using it - debug, and it'll tell you which line it's on, and therefore which to fix.

Comment: Do you also use `.Value` everywhere in the customer request?

Comment: Do you have a callstack for the exception? it will show you the line with the error. If not, why not? This will only be the first of your worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update, you don't set anything for `CarModel` and `CarMake`...

So I don't see how you could retrieve them.

To avoid error, without managing the real problem, you need null checks :

```
CarRegistration = n.Element("CarRegistration")!= null ? n.element("CarRegistration").Value : string.Empty,
                //etc.
```

By the way, you could use Xml.Linq syntax instead of a stringBuilder to write your Xml !

```
var car = new XElement("CarType");
car.Add(new XElement("CarRegistration"), textBox30.Text);
//etc.
var NewStudent = car.ToString();//NewStudent for a car, weird ;)
```

Comment: Thank you, not sure why I was thinking update only updated the requested fields. Bahhh!